# How to use timer with web-browser in console application in c#?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, timer, webbrowser-control, windows

I am trying to load multiple url's one after another and I am using timer.tick function so that all ajax data loads in the webpage.

1. But problem is that console application closes before timer.tick is call after interval of timer because timer is of new thread?

**Note****:** I am also using [STAThread] for main method because if I dont use it it showing an warning regarding .pdb file not loaded

2. What is the role of [STAThread] here?

How to solve this problem. Is there any way to make it wait till timer is stopped.
Here is code samples below.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        OpenURLInBrowser("https://www.google.co.in/");
    }
private static void OpenURLInBrowser(String url)
    {
        if (!url.StartsWith("http://") && !url.StartsWith("https://"))
        {
            url = "http://" + url;
        }
        try
        {
            webbrowser.AllowNavigation = true;
            webbrowser.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;
            webbrowser.Navigate(new Uri(url));
            WaitTillPageLoadsCompletly(DynamicWebBrowser.webbrowser);
            timer.Interval = 10000;
            timer.Tick += Timer_Tick;
            timer.Start();
        }
        catch (UriFormatException)
        {
            return;
        }
    }
    private static void Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (webbrowser.ReadyState == WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
        {
            HtmlElement element = webbrowser.Document.GetElementById("loadingDiv");
            if (element != null)
            {
                Console.Write(element.OuterHtml + "\n\n\n");
                Console.WriteLine("==============================================================================================================" + "\n\n\n");
                timer.Stop();
                int count = 0;
                while (count < 2)
                {
                    OpenURLInBrowser("https://www.google.co.in/");
                    count++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
private static void WaitTillPageLoadsCompletly(WebBrowser webBrControl)
    {
        WebBrowserReadyState loadStatus;
        int waittime = 20000;
        int counter = 0;
        while (true)
        {
            loadStatus = webBrControl.ReadyState;
            Application.DoEvents();
            if ((counter > waittime) || (loadStatus == WebBrowserReadyState.Uninitialized) || (loadStatus == WebBrowserReadyState.Loading) || (loadStatus == WebBrowserReadyState.Interactive))
            {
                break;
            }
            counter++;
        }
        counter = 0;
        while (true)
        {
            loadStatus = webBrControl.ReadyState;
            Application.DoEvents();
            if (loadStatus == WebBrowserReadyState.Complete && webBrControl.IsBusy != true)
            {
                break;
            }
            counter++;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You can use Console.ReadKey() to stop the console to close

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        OpenURLInBrowser("https://www.google.co.in/");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

You can use Console.ReadKey() or Console.ReadLine()
 to stop the console application exit

Comment: Yes it stops console to exit but not waiting till the web browser gets loaded completely and timer.tick function is called

Answer (score 0):

You're going about it the wrong way. You shouldn't spawn a process (in this case the WebBrowser control) and then go into a tight loop checking for its status to change.

Instead, start the page loading, and bind code to the WebBrowser control's DocumentCompleted event. That way, when the browser has completed loading the page, it will execute the completion code (which could load the next page, or whatever you want it to do), without you having to sit and monitor it in a loop, which just wastes resources.

See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.documentcompleted(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I am trying to do this in console application. there are only functions and no pages.